# How to perform a GET request after a POST request with web-sockets

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I am currently trying to build a go API using gin for a web and mobile application. I am new to the world of WebSockets and Go so I was wondering how I would go about triggering a GET request from the client after a relevant POST request was made ie: the POST request contained the user's ID so the clients who require information regarding that user are properly updated. Currently, I have the POST and GET requests which do what I need them, but I'm a little lost about how to make the entire flow realtime using WebSockets.

Comment: WebSockets are not about GET and POST, they are about transferring messages (i.e. no specific request+response pattern). One cannot do HTTP GET and POST over a WebSocket. Note that WebSocket is not the same as a socket but is its own protocol on top of TCP sockets.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich my apologies, my understanding of websockets and sockets as a whole is weak. So how would I go about completing the objective that I had mentioned? Would server sent events be the right solution?

Comment: I don't actually understand what you are trying to do. You say that you already have the POST and GET requests - so why not just send these? And WebSockets don't offer "real-time", all they offer is to not be restricted to the classic HTTP request+response model but send and receive messages outside of this.

Comment: SSE or Websockets can be used.  The client receives messages from the server and issues a get request on receipt of a message indicating that an update is available.  The server maintains a collection of client connections keyed by user ID.  On receipt of the a POST for a user ID, the server sends a message to all client connections for that ID.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I believe you have the closest approach to what I wish to accomplish. Suppose I have a POST endpoint called check-in and a GET endpoint called attendees, you are recommending that at the end of the POST handler, I send an SSE to the users I wish to, and from that event trigger on the client-side, perform a GET request to attendees - is this your recommendation?

Comment: You need a third endpoint for the SSE, call it 'wait-new-checkin'. The client opens SSE connection to endpoint and issues GET request for attendees on receipt of message.  The server maintains collection of active SSE connections and sends messages to appropriate connections on receipt of a new checkin.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Ah got ya, so in the context of Go and Gin, how would I trigger the new SSE endpoint from the POST endpoint? Would it be a channel? Also thank you for your help thus far - much appreciated

Comment: I believe I can make a copy of the Gin context at the POST endpoint and call the handler of the SSE endpoint from the POST handler

Comment: A channel is a good choice.  The `wait-for-checkin` handler creates a channel and adds that channel to a collection. Call this the notify channel. After adding the channel to the collection, the handler selects on the notify channel and the [request context](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.Context) done channel. The endpoint sends SSE message on receipt of value on the notify channel.  The endpoint removes the notify channel from the collection when the connection is done.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this example](https://github.com/gin-gonic/examples/blob/master/server-sent-event/main.go) of server-sent-events should address the question. Once a POST handler has been called, send a flag to the GET endpoint via a channel and then send an event through there.